# Image validation rule not working as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, validationrule

Here's my validation rule:

```
public function rules() {

    $channel_id = Auth::user()->channels->first()->id;
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:30|unique:channel,name,' . $channel_id,
        'slug' => 'required|max:30|alpha_num|unique:channel,slug,' . $channel_id,
        'description' => 'max:1000',
        'channelImage' => 'image',

    ];
}

public function messages() {
    return [

        'slug.unique' => 'That  unique URL has already been taken.',
        'channelImage.image' => 'Only jpeg, jpg, png, bmp, gif and svg formats are supported.',
    ];
}
```

Although, is it not mandatory to upload channel image while filling the form, the `image` validation rule for `channelImage` works as if it's mandatory i.e. I need to upload an image every time I submit the request.

Why is working like that?? I did not mention `required` rule for `channelImage`, still why it is validating `channelImage` when I am not uploading any image?

Comment: try this 'channelImage'=>'nullable | image'

Comment: 'channelImage'=>'nullable | image' didn't work

Comment: still didn't work :(

Comment: You might have the validation on the view separate from this backend validation ?

Comment: @PritamBohra Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `form`??

Comment: I am using vue component and sending the file using formData

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`nullable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields):

```
'channelImage' => 'nullable|image',
```

Comment: 'channelImage'=>'nullable | image' didn't work. I didn't downvote

Comment: @Leo, if you downvoted would you mind letting me know why?